# I can't dynamically style my added content to my jquery mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery mobile page that has a textbox and a button. When the button is clicked, I want to add an additional textbox. However, the new textbox is not styled properly. I've tried using .trigger('create') when appending my textbox but it is still not styling.

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttxuq7dt/)

And here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="auth1" name="auth1">
    <label>Name of the Author</label>
    <div id="auth-box">
        <input type="text" name="auth1" placeholder="John Smith" style="width: 200px;" value="" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" data-inline="true" value="Add Author   " onclick="addtxt()" />
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="auth_cnt" name="auth_cnt" value="1">
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addtxt() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerHTML = '<input type = text name = "auth">';
        $('#auth-box').after(div).trigger('create');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: So you want to add style while generating textbox ?

Comment: yes, if you see my jsfiddle the new textbox isn't styled accordingly: http://jsfiddle.net/ttxuq7dt/

Comment: the style same which has been given to the first textbox, right ?

Comment: yes, I would want the same jquery mobile style as the first textbox. thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ttxuq7dt/6/

Comment: -- removed as Omar answer is more up to date --

Comment: hi try like this   window.addtxt = function()
{
     var div = document.createElement('div');

    div.className="divclassname";
    div.innerHTML = '<input type = text name = "auth">';
    
    
    $('#auth-box').after(div);
    
    $('.divclassname').find("input").textinput();
 
}